# PHP strtotime how get only time

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

When I use for example strtotime('14:30:25') I get the timestamp with the current date and time, however I want the timestamp only for the time to use in Excel time cell. So I want to get timestamp 0,604456018518518 (14:30:25) instead of 42939,6044560185 (2017-07-23 14:30:25).
It is possible?

Comment: So you basically just want how many seconds has passed since midnight? That's not really a "timestamp", though.

Comment: If you want it for  an Excel time cell, then be aware that MS Excel uses its own timestamp, which isn't a unix timestamp... you need to create an actual MS Excel timestamp

Comment: I use PHPExcel, so if I do this;
->setCellValue('C' . $i, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(strtotime($row['Ora']) - strtotime('TODAY')))
the cell contain also the date but I need only the time

Comment: Probably I can remove the integer part but I not shure it is the correct way. May be there is a better way to get only the time from the timestamp

Comment: If you're using PHPExcel, then PHPExcel actually provides functions to handle the conversion between Unix timestamps and MS Excel timestamps... but just setting a unix timestamp as a cell value will not automagically create an MS Excel timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string value for a time (e.g. `14:30:25`), and you want to set it as an MS Excel timestamp using PHPExcel, then you need to convert it first, and then set the number format mask to display it as a time:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 
    PHPExcel_Calculation_DateTime::TIMEVALUE( '13:14:15' )
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);
```

But don't try to manipulate it with `strtotime()`, because that only works with unix timestamps

Comment: Yes, this work! Thankyou very much! Just one last detail ... in Excel the cell is as custom format and not time format. Do you have any idea why is not in the time format? Instade date cells are correctly set as date format.

Comment: No I can't answer that for certain, although the newest versions of MS Excel use a slightly different set of masks than the older versions that PHPExcel has as pre-defined masks. If it's absolutely critical, you can use any time format mask that MS Excel recognises, you're not limited to the subset that's defined as built-in constants in PHPExcel

Comment: I have try also ->setFormatCode('hh:mm:ss'); but Excel still see the cell as custom format. I don't know what format it expect for the time format. However it is not critical, just wonder why.